# Read From Text File in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi

I have a text file with UTF8 encoding, and I create an application in delphi 2009 with an opendialoge , a memo and a button and write this code:

```
if OpenTextFileDialog1.Execute then
   Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenTextFileDialog1.FileName);
```

When I Run my application ,I click on the button and select my text file, in the memo i see :

"Œ ط¯ط± ط¢ظ…â€چظˆط²ط´â€Œ ع©â€چط´â€چط§ظˆط±ط²غŒâ€Œ: ط±"

the characters was not show correctly.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the file does not have a UTF-8 BOM at the beginning, then you need to tell `LoadFromFile()` that the file is encoded, eg:

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenTextFileDialog1.FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to select an encoding format in the OpenTextFile Dialog.
OpenTextFileDialog.Encodings represents a list of encodings that can be used, default list: ANSI, ASCII, Unicode, BigEndian, UTF8 and UTF7.

```
// Optionally add Encoding formats to the list:
FMyEncoding := TMyEncoding.Create;
OpenTextFileDialog1.Encodings.AddObject('MyEncoding', FMyEncoding);
// Don't forget to free FMyEncoding


var
  Encoding : TEncoding;
  EncIndex : Integer;
  Filename : String;
begin
  if OpenTextFileDialog1.Execute(Self.Handle) then
    begin
    Filename := OpenTextFileDialog1.FileName;

    EncIndex := OpenTextFileDialog1.EncodingIndex;
    Encoding := OpenTextFileDialog1.Encodings.Objects[EncIndex] as TEncoding;
    // No Encoding found in Objects, probably a default Encoding:
    if not Assigned(Encoding) then
      Encoding := StandardEncodingFromName(OpenTextFileDialog1.Encodings[EncIndex]);

    //Checking if the file exists
    if FileExists(Filename) then
      //Display the contents in a memo based on the selected encoding.
      Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName, Encoding)
```

Comment: I'm curious about this. I'm not sure what you the code is doing. What is the Encodings object all about? Could you possibly elaborate on this with some extra text and annotations please.

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of this control. Am I right that the dialog includes a drop down list which allows the user to specify the encoding? I guess this is more commonly seen when saving a file (e.g. the way Notepad does). Does this control use new style Vista dialogs or does it fall back to the legacy XP dialogs?

Comment: Yes, it includes am Encoding drop down list. This control use the XP style. The Vista style control (TFileOpenDialog) doesn't have an encoding drop down list by default, but with a few lines of code you can add one.

Comment: Yes that can be done easily enough with `IFileDialogCustomize`, IIRC.